# How do I flatten a nested promise dependency?

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise

I'm using [mondora/asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid) through a node app to use Meteor DDP via a promise pattern.

I have the following code I am rewriting from callback style, into a promise style, but am stuck on how to flatten it.

```
asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.length === 1) {
      // something
      asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { params })
        // this part feels wrong
        .then(res => {
          // something else
        });
    } else {
      // nope
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

There is a second `asteroid.call` & `then` inside the first promise response which is a promise. This part feels wrong, like it should be flat and not nested but I'm not sure how to get there.

edit:

Ended up using something like this (still not decided on whether to have the first then check for `if length === 1` and potentially immediately reject it. Anyone know what is best practice on that?

```
asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params })
  .then(res => res.length === 1 ? res : Promise.reject())
  .then(res => asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { res[0].something }))
  .then(res => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle the no found
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: the most important part about promises is the chaining, if you're not returning the promises, you're not chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting callbacks, chain promises together with .then()

A note:

I'm not sure what Promise library you are using, but the idea is to return a rejected promise from the first .then() if there is an error, otherwise you return a successful promise. The promise library will then handle the error handling for you, going to the catch block if there is a rejected promise.

```
asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params })
  .then(res => {
    res.length === 1 ? return asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { params }) : Promise.reject();
  })
  .then(res => {
    //do stuff here
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

edit:

The only issue is when you need to access *both* of the return values from the promises at the same time. When you flatten out a promise chain you lose access to the results from the previous promises.

You have a few options:

1. If you don't need the previous result then flatten out the promise chain like I did here
2. If you do need the previous value

   2a. And you don't care about the ordering of execution then use `Promise.all([promise1, promise2])`

   2b. And you do care about the ordering of the execution then you must use nested promises like you originally did.

Comment: So in t his example the `asteroid.call('Pony.finish')` would be in the second then? That would still be nested, no?

Comment: Oh I think I got it: `asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params  })
  .then(res => res.length === 1 ? res : Promise.reject())
  .then(res => asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { params }))
  .then(res => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle the no found
    console.error(err);
  });`

Comment: Is it better practice to cause the first check on length to catch or handle it within the promise chain?

Comment: Moved this comment to the answer for better formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot. On the first res there is an if to check the length. Is that good practice or is that where you would want to use the catch for? So the promise immediately rejects if length isn't 1?

Comment: I guess I would be suspicious if the asteroid.call function was returning an empty list wrapped in a promise and we are supposed to know that is an error condition.

If you can control that function: it would be idiomatic for the function to return a rejected promise if there are 0 elements in the result list that way the person calling the function doesn't have to manually reject the promise.

Answer (score 0):

If promises are nested, there is no difference between promises and callback.

Try changing your code to use promise chain:

```
asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.length === 1) {
      // something
      let p1 = asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { params });
      return p1;
    }
    else {
      // nope
    }
  })

  .then (function SomeThingElse(res2){
    // something else
    // res2 is return value from nested asteroid.call

  })

  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Since the first resolve handler returns a Promise `p1`, the invocation of the next functions in the chain (`function SomeThingElse`) is deferred until `p1` is `resolved`.

Now expanding this example:

```
asteroid.call('Pony.search', { params })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.length === 1) {
      // something
      let p1 = asteroid.call('Pony.finish', { params });
      return p1;
    }
    else {
      // nope
    }
  })

  .then (function SomeThingElse(res2){
    // something else
    // res2 is return value from nested asteroid.call

  })

  .then (function AnotherFunc(res3){

  })

  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

If `SomeThingElse` returns a `Promise`, invocation of  `AnotherFunc` is delayed until that promise is resolved.

If `SomeThingElse` does **not** return a `Promise`, `AnotherFunc` would be invoked immediately with the same parameters as 'SomeThingElse' received. In other words, both `SomeThingElse` and `AnotherFunc` are invoked when p1 is resolved.